# Drop event on input is fired before the new value is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to read the **value of an input** when some text is selected and dragged into it, so I listen for the "drop" event:

```
$input.on('drop', function() {
    console.log($input.val());
});
```

This way I get the old value (tested on Chrome 45, Firefox 41, Opera 32, Internet Explorer 9; on Safari 5.1 the `drop` event is not fired, I guess it is due to the old version not supporting HTML5).
To workaround it I scheduled the function after a short timeout for the new value to be readable:

```js
$input.on('drop', function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($input.val());
    }, 100);
});
```

and it works, but I ask:

1. is this the default behaviour?
   (If at that level it is possible applying the `preventDefault()` method, I can understand why the value is not yet updated).
2. Is it is possible **accessing the new value** without waiting the even short timeout?
   (I inspected the event properties but unfortunately did not find something interesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the default behaviour. (It's correct, but not neccessarily *desired*, most the time.)

No - the data isn't available in the drop event, in its current implementation. If it would be answer, it'd be evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items.
What you're actually seeing looks like a race condition. You can usually get around these by doing a `setTimeout`, as you have. When it's a 'real' race condition, you can use 0 as your timeout. e.g. `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 0);`.

This *does work* for your code, and I personally feel more comfortable with a `setTimeout` with 0, rather than an arbitrary number - it's an acceptable workaround, IMO.

You could, of course, use the `change` event - is that an option?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Dave, you are right, the zero timeout also works. Listening the only "change" event instead it does not work.